# Blender Python Displaying UI Table with header

Tags: python

Is it possible to create a Table using a template list that has first row as the description of the attributes the list contains.

I currently have something like this. 
[image]

It is occupying way to much space and I want to actually put the cell description only on the top centered and have only values in the grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to do this.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I wonder if its possible to register a handler on mouse clicks if user clicks an item off any item?

Comment: You can define get/set/update callbacks on RNA. But we dont have Python defined UI callbacks.